# Why is Blender moving objects with locked locations on the Y axis after exporting to FBX?

Tags: animation, export

I am exporting a model with two separate mesh objects, plus its armature to which it is rigged using Rigify. In addition, I have separate animation "clips" saved as Actions for the purpose of bringing them into Unity.

Unity import issues aside, I am having a strange problem where the rig is being translated to (0,-0.23194,0) upon completing the export. Furthermore, the rig's location is locked on all axes in the property bar.

I am guessing there is some animation data somewhere causing this, but after going through each action I couldn't find any unusual translations for the rig's root.

Is there something else I may be missing here?

For reference, I have attached an image of my FBX export settings.

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Matt

Comment: From your screen capture, looks like you are using a very old version of Blender when only 6.1 ASCII FBX exporter was available… Strongly suggest you update to latest version, and use modern 7.4 binary exporter instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you have any experience using the new 7.x binary exporter with a Unity 5.x workflow? If we could, we certainly would like to transition to using the binary exporting.

  I installed Blender 2.74 in parallel to try out the new features, and so far the exporter seems like a double edged sword with both desirable and undesirable effects in both legacy ASCII format and the new binary.

Comment: You could try with a build from [the buildbot](https://builder.blender.org/download), I already fixed a few issues in FBX code since last 2.74 release…

Answer (score 1):

Well, when I imported the FBX into Unity, it was the object called "rig" (the armature object generated by Rigify) that was being moved around. Checking that object for strange translations in each Action, I found nothing.

But I did notice a stray "LocRot" channel that didn't seem to be attached to any particular object. At least not by name. This was what was moving the rig around.
So removing this channel fixed my problem.